# function for three-dimensional display of array of binary image matrices (Python, OpenCV, C++)

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, scipy

I have available a database of medical grade CT scans. Each scan series consists of about 30 ordered slides, each parallel to the next (dimensions consistent among images). I would like to generate a three dimensional (preferably rotatable) rendering of these images.

I anticipate that I'll be able to accomplish my goal by joining series of threshholded images in binary form into numpy/scipy arrays ([image1,image2,...imageN]) and feeding the object into some sort of a display function. Does anyone know of a function that fits this description?

I apologize if my question is poorly articulated-- Please kindly request further clarification if needed.

I'm a first time poster and by no means an expert in image processing, computer vision, etc.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, you should read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). It will keep people from yelling at you, or worse, down voting you =).

Comment: @johnthexiii this place is so scary :))

Comment: Have a look at Mayavi examples: http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html